# Google Search Console coverage reports urls with sql injections

Tags: sql-injection, google-crawlers, google-search-console

In **Coverage** section I find couple of urls with **Server error 5xx**

```
https://example.com/us/en99999" union select unhex(hex(version())) -- "x"="x/restaurants/pizza-luigi
```

Surely Google does not launch these on my site.

So I assume this url either:

1. Should appear on the sitemap
2. It is generated on the site either by malicious data in the database or malicious script attached. Crawler sees this link on the site and follows it.

**Are my assumptions correct?**

What I did so far was:

I investigated and ruled out sitemap and database. Also, checked for malicious scripts attached and could not find a single thing.

The way it is constructed points me to this piece of code on every page which is used by scripts to construct url for stuff like modals etc:

```
Data.init({
    page: {
        languageCode: 'en',
        countryCode: 'us'
    },

    urls: {
        menu: 'https://example.com' + '/{country}/{lang}/restaurants/{slug}'
    }
});
```

Basically something might be appending sql injection to this variable: `languageCode`.

**How do I find it?**

**Is there any other possibility for this happening?**

***UPDATE***:

```
172.69.63.184 
Mozilla/5.0+(Linux;+Android+6.0.1;+Nexus+5X+Build/MMB29P)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/41.0.2272.96+Mobile+Safari/537.36+(compatible;+Googlebot/2.1;++http://www.google.com/bot.html)
```

and

```
172.69.71.45 
Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+Googlebot/2.1;++http://www.google.com/bot.html)
```

My logs show these entries. IPs obviously do not belong to Google, so as I assumed this is someone unsuccessfully trying to inject SQL. However, still failing to understand **why this appears on Google Search Console**. What does it have to do with it?

Comment: Your first and foremost concern should be to investigate 500 errors - **what the actual error message is**. If it's a database error, it's a very bad sign. Means your site is vulnerable to SQL injections and there are similar requests that result in 200 - successful exploits.

Comment: That's already covered. Url is hit and application throws 500. That doesn't even get near database. Besides that seems like very old way of getting version of MySQL and I'm not running MySQL. My biggest concern is how this ends up in Google Search Console.

Comment: Is it possible Google is reporting links elsewhere on the internet that link to your site? If so, perhaps the link you showed isn't generated anywhere on your site, but by an attacker somewhere else. You could look in your web server logs for that URL format and see if you can learn anything from the client IP address or the Referer.

Comment: If you believe it's only based on URLs generated on your site, then I'd work backwards to find all the ways your `{lang}` could be generated. How is that value formatted? I.e. where does it look up the value? Is there any way the repository of the `{lang}` value could have been influenced? Or the code that formats lang into URLs?

Comment: @BillKarwin - thanks. Just updated my question. IPs are listed on spam lists. Still failing to understand why this would appear on Google Search Console. I mean the idea is to crawl my page with sitemap and all links available independently from whatever spammy links are published somewhere else.

Comment: Did you understand the comment I posted above Nov 7 at 14:51?

Comment: @BillKarwin - what you are saying is that there is a possible scenario where someone setup a site with malicious links to my site and submitted it to google for indexing and now I get all that spammy request because google thinks it should index those?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Except they don't have to submit it to google for indexing. Google pretty much indexes every site, unless the site specifically prohibits them from doing so in their `robots.txt`.

Comment: @BillKarwin - it suprises me that it could be a possibility. Anyone could setup a farm of webservers or bunch of free wordpress sites with hundreds of malicious links and make life miserable for many.

Comment: Welcome to the internet! :-)

Comment: But I'm not saying that's in fact happening. I'm saying you shouldn't rule it out as a possibility. I suggested examining the *Referer* information in your web server logs for requests that include the malicious pattern. Referer is not a guaranteed header, because clients can spoof it. But it might be present.

Comment: How could google tell the difference between a valid URL to your site and an SQL injection attempt?

Comment: By looking at index of my site first (and its history). I'm telling google what I have or better said google sees itself what I have by crawling my site and now some other web tells it I have something else. Why would I care about google telling me that in the reports?

Comment: Unless it expects 404 instead of 500.